# How can I query the id of a nested array in a nested object in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

This is my verses schema

```
{
    "verses": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "happy": [
                {
                    "id": "112",
                    "versePath": "Proverbs 15:13",
                    "content": "A glad heart makes a cheerful face, but by sorrow of heart the spirit is crushed"
                }
            ],
            sad: [
                {
                    id: 113,
                    versePath: "text",
                    content: "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to query to find each object by id. I tried doing this using elemMatch but it didn't work.

```js
const verse = await Verses
    .find({ _id: id })
    .elemMatch("empathy", { _id: req.params.id, });
```

I also tried using aggregate but it wasn't working either.

```js
const verse = await Verses.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$verses" },
    { "$match": { "verses._id": req.params.id } }
])
```

By doesn't work, I mean both attempts either returned an empty array or the whole json object.
I want my result to return each nested object
id: 112,
versePath

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Was there an error?

Comment: Explain your problem briefly

Comment: @Joe There wasn't an error, it just didnt return what I wanted

Comment: Can you add what is the id you passed? and I see you are using `{ "$match": { "verses._id": req.params.id } }` but there is no `_id` in verses.

Comment: It would help to see what output you are expecting.  It also appears that the Verses schema doesn't contain a field named `empathy` and also no `_id` field in the `verses` array.

Comment: Refer this while asking question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask